# Excel - Select closest cells & condition

Tags: excel

I have a table that consists of 3 rows:

1. Student
2. Subject
3. Mark

Every student is tested on different subjects, and his marks are written in the table.

In the "Mark" row, the cells' values are numeric. The marks can go between 1 to 100.

I want to look at each student's 3 last marks (regardless of the subject), and see whether there are 2 marks that are above 80.
If positive, return true; If not - false;

For example:

1. **Student** | John | George | John | John
2. **Subject** | Math | English | Literature | Biology
3. **Mark** | 100 | 78 | 90 | 92

-> returns *true* for John

But:

1. **Student** | John | George | John | John
2. **Subject** | Math | English | Literature | Biology
3. **Mark** | *0* | 78 | 90 | 92

-> returns *false* for John

Thanks!

Comment: Why the answer is false in the second example, he has got 90 and 92, it should be true, no?

Comment: @Ilja you are right, my fault. In both examples, suppose instead it's 40 instead of 92

Comment: I edited it for clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNTIFS` function to check this.

If your marks are entered chronologically right to left, you can enter this formula in Cell A4 to flag if the Mark is in the last three (you will need to fill this formula right for all of your columsn):

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1)<4
```

If your marks are entered chronologically left to right, you can enter this formula in Cell A4 to flag if the Mark is in the last three (you will need to fill this formula right for all of your columsn):

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(CELL("address",A1)&":"&ADDRESS(1,COUNTA(1:1))),A1)<4
```

And then for each student, you could use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(1:1,"John",3:3,">80",4:4,TRUE)
```

If you had a list of the student names starting in Cell F1, you could use the formula below and fill down:

```
=COUNTIFS($1:$1,F1,$3:$3,">80",$4:$4,TRUE)
```

---

**Edit**: included variations for Marks entered left to right and right to left.

Comment: Hey, I need to look at the last 3 grades of each student and tell whether 2 of them exceed 80

Comment: I don't get it, how exactly does your formula count 2 marks above 80 of the last 3 (that belong to the same user)?

Comment: How do you know which were the last 3?

Comment: If I did it in SQL, it would be like: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE mark >80 AND student ='John' DESC LIMIT 3"